# WP Rewrite structure page with id parameter ?id=[id] to /id/[id]

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

Now I have a page Detail Field (slug: `detail-field`, template name: `Detail field template`)

Currently, I use parameter `?id=[id]` for send data to this page: `http://example.com/detail-field?id=69`. Base on `$_GET['id']` It will get data of field and show to front-end.

But this slug not good for SEO and have some problems when share to facebook social. So I want to change it to `http://example.com/detail-field/id/69`

I'm not good at rewrite and I don't know where to start to do this. Can you guys help me?

Comment: Please check my answer, and reply your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress Rewrite Structure:

Add Below function in function.php

```
function myplugin_rewrite_tag_rule() {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%detail-field%', '([^&]+)' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^detail-field/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?detail-field=$matches[1]','top' );
}
add_action('init', 'myplugin_rewrite_tag_rule', 10, 0);
```

Then reset permalink.

Hope this works for you.